# ConnectIQ: Access of internal sensors

Tags: garmin, connectiq

I want to develop an application with eclipse project type "Watch-App".

Basically I'm interested to get the Temperature and Speed **without** any **external sensor**. My watch (Fenix 3) should support this actually.

I made a little test application.

- On the simulator I get the temperatur as soon as I enable Simulation->FIT Data->Simulate Data.
- On the real watch (fenix 3), I don't get any temperatur updates with the same code

Code:

```
//! Constructor
function initialize()
{
    Snsr.setEnabledSensors( [Snsr.SENSOR_TEMPERATURE] );
    Snsr.enableSensorEvents( method(:onSnsr) );
    string_HR = "---temp";
}

function onSnsr(sensor_info)
{
    var HR = sensor_info.temperature;
    var bucket;
    if( sensor_info.temperature != null )
    {
        string_HR = HR.toString().substring(0, 2) + " temp";
        //Add value to graph
        HR_graph.addItem(HR);
    }
    else
    {
        string_HR = "temp";
    }

    Ui.requestUpdate();
}
```

Question: How can I access the internal sensors of the watch?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently there is not a way for apps to access the internal sensors. This has been a hugely requested feature though, so hopefully it will get added in to Toybox soon. It would be fun to get to play with the IMU, temperature, and such.

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, ConnectIQ doesn't expose the temperature as determined by the built-in sensors. It only works with ANT+ temperature sensors (i.e., the Garmin Tempe) at the moment.